# Fastapi Use generic in Depends function

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to build a generic CRUD class.
But after the UserCRUD class that inherits it is instantiated, I get an error while registering the route.
**all code:**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Query
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise
from tortoise.expressions import Q
from tortoise.models import Model

CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
FilterSchemaType = TypeVar("FilterSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)

class Users(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    username = fields.CharField(max_length=16)
    email = fields.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = fields.TextField(null=True)
    created_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Params(BaseModel):
    page: int = Query(1, ge=1)
    limit: int = Query(10, gt=0, le=200)

class CRUD(Generic[CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType, FilterSchemaType]):
    order_by_list = []

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.api = APIRouter(prefix=f'/{self.model.__name__}')

    def build_query(self, filters: FilterSchemaType):
        search = filters.model_dump()
        query = Q(is_delete=0)
        query &= Q(**{f'{k}__contains' if isinstance(v, str) else k: v for k, v in search.items() if v is not None})
        return query

    async def read_all(self, filters: FilterSchemaType = Depends(), params: Params = Depends()):
        queryset = self.model.filter(self.build_query(filters))
        count = await queryset.count()
        result = await queryset.order_by(*self.order_by_list).distinct().offset((params.page - 1) * params.limit).limit(
            params.limit).values()
        return count, result

    async def read(self, obj_id: int):
        obj = await self.model.get(id=obj_id)
        return await CreateSchemaType.from_tortoise_orm(obj)

    async def create(self, obj_in: CreateSchemaType):
        obj = await self.model.create(**obj_in.model_dump())
        return obj

    async def update(self, obj_id: int, obj_in: UpdateSchemaType):
        await self.model.filter(id=obj_id).update(**obj_in.model_dump())
        return await self.read(obj_id)

    async def delete(self, obj_id: int) -> None:
        obj = await self.model.get(id=obj_id)
        await obj.delete()

    def get_urls(self):
        self.api.add_api_route('/list', endpoint=self.read_all, methods=['GET'])
        self.api.add_api_route('/create', endpoint=self.create, methods=['POST'])
        self.api.add_api_route('/{id:int}/change', endpoint=self.update, methods=['PUT'])
        self.api.add_api_route('/{id:int}/del', endpoint=self.delete, methods=['DELETE'])
        self.api.add_api_route('/{id:int}/details', endpoint=self.read, methods=['GET'])
        return self.api

    @property
    def urls(self):
        return self.get_urls()


class UpdateUser(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str

class CreateUser(UpdateUser):
    password: str

class FilterUser(BaseModel):
    username: Optional[str] = Query(None, description="username")
    email: Optional[str] = Query(None, description="email")

class UserCRUD(CRUD[CreateUser, UpdateUser, FilterUser]):
    order_by_list = ['-created_at']

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(model=Users)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    app = FastAPI()
    register_tortoise(
        app, db_url="sqlite://:memory:", modules={"models": ["__main__"]}, generate_schemas=True
    )
    routes = UserCRUD()
    app.include_router(routes.urls, prefix='/api')
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

**The following is the error message：**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyProject\NewFast\test\test.py", line 108, in <module>
    app.include_router(routes.urls, prefix='/api')
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyProject\NewFast\test\test.py", line 76, in urls
    return self.get_urls()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyProject\NewFast\test\test.py", line 67, in get_urls
    self.api.add_api_route('/list', endpoint=self.read_all, methods=['GET'])
  File "D:\PyProject\NewFast\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 643, in add_api_route
    route = route_class(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\PyProject\NewFast\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 489, in __init__
    self.dependant = get_dependant(path=self.path_format, call=self.endpoint)
 
  ...                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 2449, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: ~FilterSchemaType is not a callable object
```

I am using CreateUser, UpdateUser, FilterUser in UserCRUD class
Replaced the original CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType, FilterSchemaType. Why does this error still occur? How should it be fixed?
Thanks!!!

Comment: `FilterSchemaType` is an input model and not a dependency; you don't need to use `= Depends()` with it.